# Font Face issue for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

i searched through Stack overflow but fail to find a solution in regards to the problems i face...I believe many people is facing the same problem as well but i am not sure why their solutions can't work on mine.

The Problem:
This is regarding @font-face.

The code on CSS:

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'JaguarJCBold';
src: url('fonts/jagb____-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/jagb____-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/jagb____-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/jagb____-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/jagb____-webfont.svg#JaguarJCBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'TrajanProBold';
src: url('fonts/trajanprobold-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/trajanprobold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/trajanprobold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/trajanprobold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/trajanprobold-webfont.svg#TrajanProBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'TrajanProRegular';
src: url('fonts/trajanproregular-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/trajanproregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/trajanproregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/trajanproregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/trajanproregular-webfont.svg#TrajanProRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}



@font-face {
font-family: 'MyriadProBlack';
src: url('fonts/myriadpro-black-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/myriadpro-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/myriadpro-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/myriadpro-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/myriadpro-black-webfont.svg#MyriadProBlack') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'MyriadProRegular';
src: url('fonts/myriadproreg-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/myriadproreg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/myriadproreg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/myriadproreg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/myriadproreg-webfont.svg#MyriadProRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Does anyone know how to make this work for google chrome to allow my fonts to take effect?

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what your problem is.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I update the code to the coorect one so others can take alook if the face the same problem...The problem is stated below the block of code...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Font Squirrel Font Face generator:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

It will give you all the correct CSS for every possible browser.

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is set up your fonts so that they're ready to use in your css file. You need to apply the font to what ever piece of text you wish to style. You would do this the same way you would when using any other web safe font.

eg.

```
.yourElement {
  font: 30px JaguarJCBold;
}
```